# Unable to initiate a new conversation with botframework and Microsoft teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to follow the steps here: https://github.com/getazureready/teamsdev/blob/main/Lab%204%20-%20Conversational%20Bots.md (Exercise 3). I am running this as instructed:

```
await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
await turnContext.sendActivity(message);
});
```

However, this is not starting a new conversation in the channel, it replies to the same conversation initiated by the user. How do we start a new conversation in the channel?

Answer (score 1):

`conversationReference` has an `id` property inside there, which has the actual main chat id, and can also have a reference to a specific message on the end, e.g.:

1. [long string] = conversation itself, vs
2. [long string];messageid=[short string]

if you use option 2, it will reply to an existing thread, but without that it will start a new thread.

So, in your context, modify the `conversationReference`'s ID and remove the `;messageid=[short string]` part

Comment: Hi @M365 Dev, Please let us know does that help clarify.